# invalid column value in where clause in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a function which would populate a datatable with the contents of a table. But its showing an annoying invalid column name error with the value I give in the WHERE clause.

```
public static DataTable GetRequests(string empid)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStr"];
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
   {
      connection.Open();
      SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
      SqlDataAdapter sAdap = new SqlDataAdapter();                
      sqlcmd.Connection = connection;
      sqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
      sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select * from requests Where emp_id=P001";                
      sAdap.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
      sAdap.Fill(dt);
   }
   return dt;            
}
```

Now with this i am getting the error at

```
sAdap.fill
```

and the error is

```
invalid column name P001
```

I'm stumped at this. Any ideas why I'm facing this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a string constant, surround it with single quotes. 'P001' or better still, paramaratise it.

Answer (score 2):

You need string delimiters around the value. Change the line to:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select * from requests Where emp_id='P001'";
```

with the single quotes around P001 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quote.

```
where emp_id='P001'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your P001 data is a string type. Try quoting it with single quotes before feeding it in as an sql string.

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select * from requests Where emp_id='P001'";
```

If that doesn't work (though it should) you can try the like statement as in:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select * from requests Where emp_id like 'P001'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your (apparrently) text criteria with single quotes:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select * from requests Where emp_id = 'P001'";
```